# React - strange data looping behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of months that I'm displaying along the x-axis of a graph. Using `date-fns` package to format the dates.

In `this.props.data`:

```
[
    {
        "month": 11,
        "year": 2020,
    },
    {
        "month": 12,
        "year": 2020,
    },
    ...
]
```

A method creates an array of DOM nodes:

```
  renderXAxis() {
    const items = [];

    if (this.props.data.length) {
      for (const data of this.props.data) {
        const month = formatDate(setMonth(new Date(), data.month - 1), 'MMM');

        items.push(
          <div className="Chart__x-axis__item" key={month + data.year}>
            <div className="Chart__x-axis__item__month">{month}</div>
          </div>,
        );
      }
    }

    return items;
  }
```

In my render method, I call:

```
<div className="Chart__x-axis">{this.renderXAxis()}</div>
```

It renders the xAxis with all items displaying the same month. What is weird to me is that if I change the DOM node that gets pushed to the item array to:

```
    items.push(
      <div className="Chart__x-axis__item" key={month + data.year}>
        <div className="Chart__x-axis__item__month">{`${month}`}</div>
      </div>,
    );
```

or

```
    items.push(
      <div className="Chart__x-axis__item" key={month + data.year}>
        <div className="Chart__x-axis__item__month">{formatDate(setMonth(new Date(), data.month - 1), 'MMM')}</div>
      </div>,
    );
```

then the months all render as they should. I don't understand why or what is going on..

Comment: could you share the codes for `formatDate` and `setMonth`?

Comment: @Sphinx those are functions from the `date-fns` package https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns

Comment: You didn't mentioned which month is the same. Is it last month in data? Or first? Or random? My guess is that `{month}` is executed lazily, components pushed to array binds variable from for loop scope lazily so it binds last value from this scope so last month. Try Array.map instead as a proof (map's callback scope can't interfere each other).